# Rails: User view is looking for user/assets? Assets routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, asset-pipeline

I can't get the routing for the assets right.

When I open localhost:3000/users/1 I have an

```
<img src="assets/image.png"/>
```

but I get an "no route matches" because it's looking for users/assets.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/assets/image.png"):
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an `img` tag directly you have to use the `image_tag` helper in your view:

```
<%= image_tag 'image.png' %>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `assets/` part?

Comment: who knows? maybe he is using the assets pipeline, maybe he's not, can't be sure unless the says something about it.

Comment: Thanks :) That did it! But the path had to be "/assets/image.png" ... or just "image.png". Both worked.